# Making an superclass with methods in it

Tags: java, subclass, lwjgl, superclass

I am wondering if I can make my piece of work ***smarter***. I have 2 classes:

### **Enemy class(the superclass of any enemy):**

```
package com.joetannoury.game.entity.enemy;

/**
 * Enemy's superclass!
 *
 * @author Joe Tannoury
 */
public abstract class Enemy {

    public Enemy(int EnemyID, float x, float y) {

    }

    public abstract void update(int delta);
    public abstract void render();
}
```

### **An enemy class(a subclass of enemy):**

```
package com.joetannoury.game.entity.enemy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This is an subclass of Enemy!
 *
 * @author Joe Tannoury
 */
public class E0 extends Enemy {

    private ArrayList<Float> x = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Float> y = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<Float> rotation = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean firstEnemy = false;

    public E0(float x, float y) {
        super(0, x, y);

        this.x.add(x);
        this.y.add(y);

        this.rotation.add(0.0f);
    }


    @Override
    public void update(int delta) {
        if(firstEnemy) {

            for(int i =  0; i > x.size(); i++) {



            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        if(firstEnemy) {

            for(int i =  0; i > x.size(); i++) {



            }

        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is, can I do something in the superclass so I dont need to setup the for() loop again and again in the subclasses? I dont really understand the meaning of an abstract class so if you think it shouldnt be can you be so nice and tell me why? :D

Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the nature of what you do inside the body of these loops you could potentially use the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. The idea is to put the loop in a method in the base, and introduce a different `abstract` method that performs a single step of the loop, like this:

```
public abstract class Enemy {
    ...
    public void render() {
        if(firstEnemy) {
            for(int i =  0; i > x.size(); i++) {
                doRender(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public abstract void doRender(int i);
}

public class E0 extends Enemy {
    ...
    public abstract void doRender(int i) {
        ... // Do the work for a single step of the loop in E0
    }
}
public class E1 extends Enemy {
    ...
    public abstract void doRender(int i) {
        ... // Do the work for a single step of the loop in E1
    }
}
... // And so on
```